# can r7 4800h use `amd_pstate` ? Or more specific, can linux enable CPCC without help of BIOS ? I tried but failed on legion r7000 2020

Tags: bios, firmware, amd, cpu-frequency, turbo-core

Recently I want to use new `amd_pstate` to increase cpu performance by something like overclocking or more *customization* shown [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/anyone-running-amd-pstate-active/140643/6), I followed this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_drivers) with update of `grub` and `mkinitcpio` based on my module.

```bash
$ ls /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/cpufreq/
acpi-cpufreq.ko.zst  amd_freq_sensitivity.ko.zst  amd-pstate-ut.ko.zst  p4-clockmod.ko.zst  pcc-cpufreq.ko.zst  powernow-k8.ko.zst  speedstep-lib.ko.zst

$ sudo cat  /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
# https://forum.manjaro.org/t/testing-update-2022-06-03-linux-5-18-systemd-251-gnome-42-2-nvidia-mesa-pulseaudio-perl/112820/20
MODULES=(nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm amd_pstate_ut amd_freq_sensitivity)
...
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect keyboard keymap consolefont modconf block filesystems fsck)
...
$ sudo cat  /etc/default/grub | grep -v \#
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet reboot=acpi nowatchdog nmi_watchdog=0 nvidia_drm.modeset=1 drm.debug=0x1ff nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1 processor.ignore_ppc=1 processor.ignore_tpc=1 amd_pstate=active amd_pstate.shared_mem=1 amd_pstate.enable=1 initcall_blacklist=acpi_cpufreq_init "
```

However in `journalctl` has errors

```bash
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate: the _CPC object is not present in SBIOS or ACPI disabled
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate_ut: amd_pstate_ut_acpi_cpc_valid the _CPC object is not present in SBIOS!
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate_ut: 1    amd_pstate_ut_acpi_cpc_valid         fail!
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate_ut: amd_pstate_ut_pstate_enable amd pstate must be enabled!
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate_ut: 2    amd_pstate_ut_check_enabled         fail!
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate_ut: 3    amd_pstate_ut_check_perf         success!
Jun 07 11:25:08 CzgArch kernel: amd_pstate_ut: 4    amd_pstate_ut_check_freq         success!
```

---

Then in above wiki, I found this

> Change Enable *CPPC* from Auto to Enabled, or any similar settings in your **UEFI**. If they are not present, consult the **vendor website** for an update.

I use grub based on efi, and I checked my vendor web for bios update, but not newer since my current version:

```bash
$ ls /boot/efi 
 EFI  'System Volume Information'
$ sudo dmidecode -t bios -q
BIOS Information
        Vendor: LENOVO
        Version: EUCN39WW
...
                UEFI is supported
```

---

##### check support

Also, after reading kernel [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/amd-pstate.html), I checked whether my cpu and kernel may support `amd_pstate`. based on this forum [Q&A](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-enable-amd-pstate/123720/2), I know the current *kernel* support `amd_pstate`.  (the `CONFIG_X86_AMD_PSTATE_UT=m` is same as what the kernel doc want.)

```bash
$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep PSTATE
CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y
CONFIG_X86_AMD_PSTATE=y
CONFIG_X86_AMD_PSTATE_UT=m
```

I also [check](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/is-the-amd-pstate-driver-included-in-5-17-rc1-kernel/99978/8) *cpu* support

```bash
$ lscpu | grep -e 'cppc\|msr' 
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca
```

---

##### try update firmware

After viewing this [post](https://www.phoronix.com/news/AMD-P-State-Linux-5.17), maybe changing firmware in linux directly instead of using BIOS to communicate with the hardware is one solution. However I found no updates.

```bash
$ fwupdmgr get-updates
Firmware metadata has not been updated for 30 days and may not be up to date.
Update now? (Requires internet connection) [y|N]: y
Updating lvfs
Downloading…             [*********************************      ] Less than one minute remaining…Request failed : Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 142.251.42.238:443
Retrying in 15 seconds
Downloading…             [************************************** ] Less than one minute remaining…
Successfully downloaded new metadata: 0 local devices supported
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140
 • MZVLB512HBJQ-000L2
 • System Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • USB2.1 Hub
No updatable devices
```

---

p.s. There is [one topic](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/amd-pstate-driver-support-for-AMD-laptops/m-p/5135917?page=1#5599568) related with cpcc on 'T14s Gen1' laptop in lenove community, but I don't find contents related with my laptop legion r7000 there.

---

Q:

1- Does above problem resulted by **no CPCC** on my machine?

If so, Do my cpu and installed kernel support CPCC as I listed above in section **'check support'** and is **BIOS** the root cause of unavailability of CPCC ?

If it is the BIOS problem, is there one way to use CPCC without help of BIOS? Or more specific, can I make small modification to my *firmware* in linux to enable CPCC just like above 'one topic' says ?

2- How to achieve above '[one topic](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/amd-pstate-driver-support-for-AMD-laptops/m-p/5135917?page=1#5599568)' 'Messing around in the firmware'(i.e. view contents in firmware.)?